# EditorGUILayout Popup not accepting changes after drop down choice changes

Tags: popup, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a custom editor with a list of extension file types that will allow the user to select which "Folder" to be put in. The problem I'm having is that the selected index of the popups (I have an array of them based on the number of extensions that need to be moved) doesn't change and remains in the last position.

[image]

```
public class ExtensionWindow : EditorWindow
{
    ExtensionBank extBank;

    string[] exts;
    public bool[] extToggles;

    public static List<string> extensions;
    public static List<string> categories;

    public static Vector2 scrollPosition;

    [MenuItem("Build Master's Dream  / Organize Files")]
    static void Organize()
    {
        ExtensionWindow myWindow = (ExtensionWindow)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(ExtensionWindow), true, "Extensions");
        myWindow.minSize = new Vector2(300.0f, 300.0f);
        myWindow.maxSize = new Vector2(300.0f, 300.0f);
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        //Get all Category names and store them in a List<>
        LoadFolderNames();
        LoadFolders();

        extBank = new ExtensionBank();

        //Populate the bank of Extensions from the .txt file
        bool success;
        success = extBank.PopulateList();

        exts = new string[extBank.GetNumOfExtensions];

        if (success)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < extBank.GetNumOfExtensions; i++)
                string shortExtensions = extBank.GetExtensions(i);
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        //extToggles = new bool[extBank.GetNumOfExtensions];

        int[] index = new int[extBank.GetNumOfExtensions];
        int selectedIndex = 0;

        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(0, 0, 300, 300));
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
        scrollPosition = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPosition);

        for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++)
        {
            index[i] = EditorGUILayout.Popup(extBank.GetExtensions(i), index[i], categories.ToArray(), GUILayout.Width(275));
           EditorGUILayout.Space();
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Make Your Dream Come True", EditorStyles.miniButtonLeft))
        {
            string[] shortCategories = categories.ToArray();

            AssetDatabase.Refresh();
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }

    void LoadFolders()
    {
        foreach (string cat in categories)
        {
            string projectPath = Application.dataPath + "/";
            if (cat != "Select Category") ;
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(projectPath + cat);
            }
        }
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
    }

    void BeginMoveOperation(string ext, string cat)
    {
        Debug.Log("Data path is: " + Application.dataPath.ToString());

        string localPath = Application.dataPath;

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(localPath);
        FileInfo[] info = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
        foreach (FileInfo f in info)
        {
            Debug.Log("Name is: " + f.Name);
            Debug.Log("Extension is: " + f.Extension);
            MoveAssetsIntoFolders(f.Name, f.Extension, f.FullName);
        }
    }

    static void MoveAssetsIntoFolders(string fileName, string extension, string oldPath)
    {

    }

    void LoadFolderNames()
    {
        var path = "Assets/Scripts/Editor/Extensions.txt";

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            try
            {
                var fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(path);
                categories = new List<string>();
                foreach (var line in fileContent)
                {
                    if (line != "")
                    {
                        if ((line.Substring(0, 1) != "" || line.Substring(0, 1) != null) && line.Substring(0, 1) != ".")
                        {
                            categories.Add(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Log(ex);
            }
        }
    }
    void OrganizeScripts()                  
    {
        Assembly _assembly = Assembly.Load("Assembly-CSharp");

        foreach (Type type in _assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.IsClass)
            {
                if (type.BaseType.FullName.Contains("MonoBehaviour"))           //Standard Unity Scripts
                {

                }
                else if (type.BaseType.FullName.Contains("Editor"))             //Unity Editor Files
                {

                }
            else                                                            //All others, likely .js scripts
                {
```

[image: Screen grab of Code errors]

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears that you are creating the index array every time the method is called, so no matter what you assign to index[i], the next time the frame is called it all gets reset to zero.  So what i would do is either assign the value to your extBank or make the index array a member variable and not a local variable.

```
int[] index = new int[0];
void OnGUI()
{
    //extToggles = new bool[extBank.GetNumOfExtensions];
    if(index.Length != extBank.GetNumOfExtensions)
        System.Array.ReSize(ref index, extBank.GetNumOfExtensions);
    int selectedIndex = 0;

    GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(0, 0, 300, 300));
    EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
    scrollPosition = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPosition);

    for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++)
    {
        index[i] = EditorGUILayout.Popup(extBank.GetExtensions(i), index[i], categories.ToArray(), GUILayout.Width(275));
       EditorGUILayout.Space();
    }
    //rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the reason here is that you`re passing zero as the 'selectedIndex' parameter of the [EditorGUILayout.Popup](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Popup.html) method.
This parameter should contains currently selected index from your storage.
Like that:

```
index = EditorGUILayout.Popup("Label", index, displayedOptions);
```

Idea is to pass as the 'selectedIndex' parameter the same variable that you`re using to get the return value from the method.

```
private List<CharacterState> selected;

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (selected == null)
        {
            selected = new List<CharacterState>();
            foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CharacterState)))
            {
                selected.Add((CharacterState) value);
            }
        }

        int[] index = selected.Select(x=>(int)x).ToArray();

        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(0, 0, 300, 300));
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
        scrollPosition =
        EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPosition);

        var vals = Enum.GetNames(typeof (CharacterState));

        for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++)
        {
            var v = EditorGUILayout.Popup(((CharacterState)index[i]).ToString(), index[i], vals, GUILayout.Width(275));
            index[i] = v;
            EditorGUILayout.Space();
        }

        var j = 0;
        foreach (var i in index)
            selected[j++] = (CharacterState)i;

        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
```

As you can see, I cast all the enum values to int[] as you do, but after Popup method call I do another iteration of the array with indices in order to store the values in the 'selected' List.

Comment: Can you post your code where you`re trying to do so please?

Comment: Here's the entire class, all the items that link to it, I can pass also.

Comment: Also it seems strange that you`re creating new array in every OnGUI call and using it to store the values you get from user input. Is it possible that those values just arent saved in extBank (or any other member of your class) after OnGUI call?

Comment: They are, However I cannot do an Enum to a List<> which is what extBank is, so i temporarily store them into an array for display purposes then set the categories later on.

Comment: Well, I tried to reproduce this issue and I still think that problem is that you do not store the values you get from Popup method. I`ll edit my answer to show you what exactly I`m doing.

Comment: I tried replicating that code block, yet the List<> does not contain a method group for Select, what am I missing?

Comment: Select is LINQ extension method, so you have to add System.Linq to the list of 'using' directives.

Comment: Three more errors pop up, involving conversion from my class (CategoryUnit) to int, I'll upload a screen grab of it above.

Comment: This is because your CategoryUnit is a class. I thought you`re working with an enumeration. Few comments above you said that you 'cannot do an Enum to a List<>') Anyway, all you have to do is extract currently selected values in the beginning of OnGUI() to some array variable, iterate that array while calling array[index] = Popup(array[index]), and then put the values you have in an array back to your collection.